# JavaScript event looping only once with no output

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I'm writing a JS code to calculate a final grade given some individual grades and output the result in the html page but when I trigger the event and function it loops only once in my for loop without reaching the rest of the code (I checked using print statements) but I don't understand what is wrong with the loop that's making the rest of the code not be reached.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Problem 2</title>
        <script src="grades.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Grade Calculator</h1>
        <form id ="myForm">
            <div id="assignments">
            HW <input type="text" size="1"/> / <input type="text" size="1"/><br/>
            HW <input type="text" size="1"/> / <input type="text" size="1"/><br/>
            HW <input type="text" size="1"/> / <input type="text" size="1"/>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="curve"/> Curve +5?
            </div>

            <div id="resultsarea">
                <p>
                    <!--add buttons here -->
                    <button type="button" id="comp">Compute</button>
                    <button type="button" id="clr">Clear</button>
                </p>

                <!-- add results here -->
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = pageLoad;

function pageLoad()
{
    var cbutton = document.getElementById("comp");
    cbutton.onclick = compute;
}

function compute()
{
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var marks = 0;
    var total = 0;
    for (var i=1; i <= list.length; i++)
    {
        if(list[i].type == "text")
        {
            if (i%2 != 0)
            marks += list[i].value;
            else
            total += list[i].value;
        }
    }
    var result = Math.round(marks/total);
    if (document.getElementById("curve").checked)
    result += 5;
    var out = document.createElement("div");
    var t = document.createTextNode(result);
    out.appendChild(t);
    var display = document.getElementById("resultsarea");
    display.append(out);
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you're iterating from `i=1` to `i=list.length` instead of `i=0` to `i=list.length-1`?

Comment: I thought it was an indexing problem so I tried to switch it around but no there is no reason, it should start from 0

Comment: have you had a chance to test this, tarek?

Answer (score 0):

Array value starts from 0.try i=0 and i<=list.length-1.you are not counting first list element.

you are starting from list[1].type not list[0].type.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code.

First:

`for (var i=1; i <= list.length; i++)`

Should be:

`for (var i=1; i <= list.length - 1; i++)`

Because array is start from 0.

But, I think it's should be start from 0 instead 1 like this:

`for (var i=0; i < list.length; i++)`

Second:

`display.append(out);`

Should be:

`display.appendChild(out);`

There is no `append` method, use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) instead.

Comment: I know the indexing was off I was just experimenting and forgot to revert the values but I fixed that and the appendChild but there is still no output :/

Comment: What do you mean with no output?

Comment: <= list.length would check for an index that is equal to the length of the array, which would be an index higher than what exists (since they start at 0)

Answer (score 0):

NodeLists (as well as arrays in JavaScript) are zero-indexed, their last element is at `length-1`. Therefore, the loop needs to be

```
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++)
// or
for (var i=0; i<=list.length-1; i++) // uncommon
```

to access only items in the list that exist. Otherwise, they would result in `undefined`, and accessing its `value` property throws an exception which stops your whole function - so that nothing is getting output. You should be able to see the exception in your [[error] console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the answers and no one seems to have the main problems with this... so:

```
...
for (var i=0; i <= list.length-1; i++)
{
    if(list[i].type == "text")
    {
        if (i%2 == 0)
        marks += parseInt(list[i].value);
        else
        total += parseInt(list[i].value);
    }
}
var result = Math.round(parseFloat(marks / total)*100);
...
```

you were not parsing the values to ints, which meant they were concatenated instead of added.... then you were doing integer division on something that would have been 0-1 (will always be 0 or 1 after rounding), so I multiplied by 100 first... also your i%2 != 0 was assinging to the wrong var, so i changed it.. here is a jsfiddle demonstrating it works.. http://jsfiddle.net/6Y8xY/1/